# How long does a Scala Spark job take to process a million lines in a file?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have a file called file1 in HDFS that contains paths of several files:

```
this/is/path1
this/is/path2
this/is/path3
.
.
.
this/is/path1000000
```

If I get all the lines from this file as a list by executing the following line in Scala,

```
val lines=Source.fromFile("/my/path/file1.txt").getLines.toList
```

and if I use a 'for' loop as follows, to process each line of file1 in a separate function that involves some mapping functionality for each line,

```
for(i<-lines){
val firstLines=sc.hadoopFile(i,classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text]).flatMap {
case (k, v) => if (k.get == 0) Seq(v.toString) else Seq.empty[String]
}
}
```

how long will this take to run, given that file1 contains roughly more than a million lines? This scala job has been running on my machine for more than an hour and I would like to know if it has gotten stuck anywhere or is going through an infinite loop, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bit of a loaded question. But it shouldn't take long in general. My guess is something has gone wrong. From personal experience, I would guess you don't have enough executors available.

Memory gets a lot of focus with spark, but the number of available executors has given me more fits than memory issues. Especially because you will see behavior like this where it won't error out. It will just stall indefinitely.

That said, that is just a guess with very little knowledge about the job and env. Time to debug on your part and see if you can't find the issue or come back with a more specific problem/question.